# How to get elapsed time between a javascript Date function and a database date?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have short script to store employee clock in and clock out time in database.

**markup**

```
     <input id='clocked_in_time' name='clocked_in_time' value='' type='text'>
<input id='clocked_out_time' name='clocked_out_time' value='' type='text'>
```

**script**

```
<script>
document.getElementById('clocked_in_time').value = Date();
document.getElementById('clocked_out_time').value = Date();
</script>
```

**output**

```
Fri Mar 17 2017 22:21:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

The output is fine because that is exactly how my client wants to see it as it is international. But the problem now I need to calculate the difference between clock in time and clock out time.

One thing I have tried is to stock getHours(), getMinutes() and getSeconds() in separate columns in the database as follow:
[image]

Then client-side do something like this:

```
<?=$attendance['timeouthour'] - $attendance['timeinhour'];?>
```

While this works, I need to get more specific and calculate minutes and seconds all together... How can I accomplish this? Or is there an easier way to go about solving this?

Comment: clock in time and clock out time are the same with what you got.. any more to this?

Comment: Your problem is a bit unclear. We don't know what you are already storing in your database. Are you storing clockin and clockout time in it ? If yes then you can perform arithmetic operations on Date objects.

Comment: youre missing a closing quote: `id='clocked_in_time`

Comment: @SwannPolydor: I have updated my question so I dont think its a duplicate.

Comment: why not do the comparison in the backend, and not in JS?

Comment: @CodeGodie: Id be pleased to know exactly how `:-)`

Comment: @SebastianFarham You should probably store timestamps. The Date API of Javacript is lacking some functionality here is how to get it.

`Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)`

Store the timestamps and then you will be able to recreate Date objects based on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your database columns so that they are of DATETIME type. Store your information so that they are of DATETIME, then you can make the comparison in the backend, use PHP to retrieve information from Mysql using this query:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in) AS Duration
FROM my_table
```

Once retrieved, change the format of the date to match your user's expectations.

Comment: This looks good. Im about to test it out right away. But out of pure ignorance how would you join such a query with this existing query? `SELECT * FROM timesheets INNER JOIN employees ON timesheets.employee_id=employees.employee_id INNER JOIN users ON employees.username=users.username WHERE employees.employee_id`

Comment: `SELECT * , DATEDIFF(t.time_out, t.time_in) AS Duration
FROM timesheets t
INNER JOIN employees e ON t.employee_id=e.employee_id
INNER JOIN users u ON e.username=u.username
WHERE e.employee_id`

Comment: if you need to refactor, yes. The comparison should be made at the data layer for faster results. Also dates should be stored properly not as strings.

Comment: Thanks. So I have converted the string using toIsoString() which insert in database. Your query seems to also work but when I do  `<?=$attendance['timeouthour'] - $attendance['timeinhour'];?> ` the output is `-2017` was it intended to be used like that or did I miss something? (also dont be mad if you ask a question and I dont reply right away. Im on my way to crash. Its late here.)

Comment: Cool. If the query worked, than you no longer need to subtract in PHP. Instead you need to use the variable `Duration` so if `$attendance` represents a sql row, then it would be `$attendance['Duration']` . Does that work?

Comment: It returns blank `:(`

Comment: sorry to hear that.. are you adding the dates on a columns with DATETIME type?

Comment: Little attention span problem. I had forgotten to convert the timeouthour toIsoString() so nothing was getting inserted. Now it is getting inserted but the result returns `0`

Comment: Ok little adjustment I had to do with your query instead of using `DATEDIFF` I switched to `TIMEDIFF` which works! If you want to update your answer I give you the  creds.

Comment: Ah cool, glad you were able to figure it out. That does make sense. I will update the answer.